# Limit in 2 variables for $r=||(x,y)||$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that the function

$$f(x,y)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{r^2-1}\right), if \;r<1$$
$$f(x,y)=0, if \; r \geq 1$$

Where $r =||(x,y)||$ is continuous in $R^2$

If $r>1$ or $r<1$ it is clearly continuous. But I need to analyze when $r \to 1:$
It looks like a transformation for polar coordinates, but I can't find the equivalent limit in $ R^2$ when $r \to 1.$ What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Polar coordinates are (almost) offtopic. Note that $f(x,y)=g(h(x,y))$ where $h(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $g(t)=\exp(1/(t-1))$ if $0\leqslant t\lt1$ and $g(t)=0$ if $t\geqslant1$. Can you show that $g$ and $h$ are continuous?